# Software needed to cross-reference geocodes to a Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geocoding, intersection

I do not have any GIS software except Microsoft MapPoint.

I  have State district KML and Shapefiles of the districts.

I am assuming these are for ArcGIS.

I do not want to draw maps.

Instead, I am looking for a program that, if I give it one of 500,000 geocodes, it will tell me from a database perspective which District it is in.

I am looking for analytical information not visual.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles are the de facto interchange format for GIS data, ArcGIS can open them but so can many other programs. I'd suggest downloading [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/), it's a free alternative to ArcGIS that will do what you need.

There are a few ways to do what you describe but the simplest operation is called an [Intersect](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Intersect), you would take your two layers (districts and your geocoded locations) and QGIS will tell you which district each point (I'm assuming they are points) falls inside. In QGIS this command can be found under the Vector > Geoprocessing menu.

[image]

You would choose your points layer as the Input layer and your Districts shapefile as the Intersect layer. The resulting shapefile will consist of all your points which fall within a District, with the ID of the district (assuming your District shapefile has them) attached to each point.

However, I'm a little confused as to what exactly you mean by "geocodes", geocoding is the process of assigning geographic locations to things based on other data (usually street addresses). If you have a list of 500,000 addresses, you will need to geocode them before you can use them in GIS, [this search](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=batch%20geocoding) may help. If you have a list of 500,000 locations with X and Y coordinates (like Latitude and Longitude), your task is easier. Get those locations and coordinates into a table and you can add them to QGIS using the Layers > Add Delimited Text Layer.

Comment: Dan C, Thank you very much, I am a little bit of a newbie when it comes to GIS. Since my task is to really build an association between addresses and legislative districts from a database perspective I will try to follow your instructions and use QGIS. I will be using a geocoding service to take my CASS certified addresses and give me a longitude and latitude for each address. Then I will import both the shapefiles for legislative districts and the addresses that have been assigned a longitude and latitude.  And see how it works out. Thank you again